# What will happen if U.S. stops funding U.N.?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, united-nations, international

> **Donald Trump** - "When all of our taxpayers are paying roughly 22 percent of the  budget, I think they do expect to see a more efficient and an organization that's more objective and more in keeping with our values" .

As USA provides almost a quarter of the entire funding to USA and it funds billions of dollars to other UN organisations. Then what will happen if US entirely stops funding UN ? What kind of drastic effect will be seen ? Why do developed nations don't fund U.N. as much as U.S. ?

Is there any compulsory consideration for UN like "2% of GDP" clause of NATO when it comes to funding  ??

Comment: This is asking too many questions at once. The first two questions are speculative (“what will happen?”), the third is based on a false premise (that the US pay disproportionately much). An answer to the fourth question would show that wrong premise, but it is a duplicate of [Who and on what basis determines how much US pays for UN?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16442/who-and-on-what-basis-determines-how-much-us-pays-for-un)

Comment: [Some data about 2018 payments](http://www.un.org/en/ga/contributions/honourroll.shtml) to UN. Looks like the payments are proportional to GNP, and integer multiples of USD24307. So far the biggest contributions have come from Germany and China. Japan, UK, France and US are missing from that list. Quite likely the member nations have some leeway in scheduling their payments.

Comment: [These numbers also shed some light](https://factly.in/united-nations-budget-contributions-by-member-countries/). Looks like the US contribution is at par with its relative influence in the UN decision making process. In other words, this looks like yet another populist statement from POTUS.

Answer (score 3):

> Then what will happen if US entirely stops funding UN?

The USA will also stop having the leverage of being the most dominant nation on UN discussion and decision tables.

> What kind of drastic effect will be seen?

Some other countries will take up the role of the USA, most likely collectively.

> Why do developed nations don't fund U.N. as much as U.S.?

The USA accounts for 25% of the world's nominal GDP.

> Is there any compulsory consideration for UN like "2% of GDP" clause of NATO when it comes to funding?

I don' know. But, since, the USA is one of the founders of the UNO, it is reasonable that they would post a significant contribution to the UNO's budget.